# minio direct-csi no matches for kind "CSIDriver" in version "storage.k8s.io/v1"

Tags: kubernetes, minio

I was to setup the 4 node minio cluster in distributed mode using direct-csi driver. Based on the document I try to create the direct-csi deployment, but is failing with below error message.  I am using Kubernetes v1.17.0 cluster.

https://github.com/minio/direct-csi

```
# DIRECT_CSI_DRIVES=data{1...4} DIRECT_CSI_DRIVES_DIR=/mnt kubectl apply -k github.com/minio/direct-csi
namespace/direct-csi unchanged
storageclass.storage.k8s.io/direct.csi.min.io unchanged
serviceaccount/direct-csi-min-io unchanged
clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/direct-csi-min-io unchanged
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/direct-csi-min-io unchanged
configmap/direct-csi-config unchanged
secret/direct-csi-min-io unchanged
service/direct-csi-min-io unchanged
deployment.apps/direct-csi-controller-min-io unchanged
daemonset.apps/direct-csi-min-io unchanged
error: unable to recognize "github.com/minio/direct-csi": no matches for kind "CSIDriver" in version "storage.k8s.io/v1"
```

How to resolve this error message?

[update]
to check the CIS version:

```
kubectl explain CSIDriver
KIND:     CSIDriver
VERSION:  storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Thanks
SR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using K8s 1.17 the `CSIDriver` object [became GA in 1.18](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/csi-driver-object.html). So `storage.k8s.io/v1` will not work. If you look at [the docs](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/csi-driver-object.html#changes-from-alpha-to-beta) you can see that you have to use `storage.k8s.io/v1beta1` for Beta. So you can fork the repo and make that modification or you can do it locally.

✌️

Comment: Thanks Rico, let me test it on 1.18, see this works.